# Custom metric across rows in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to calculate metrics for my TensorFlow model across rows with a common key -- specifically precision at k for an information retrieval task -- and I'm finding this extremely nontrivial.  My data include a field that indicates the session ID of each row, and there are variable number of rows for each session ID (but small, under 100).  My task is to train across the rows as independent observations, so I don't want to group on the session ID and train per-session as it will bias the model.  The entire point of the model is to train and evaluate on individual items independently of context, but evaluate the quality of that evaluation within the context, by session IDs.

As a side note, part of the challenge I'm concerned about is data locality as I'm performing distributed training.  [However it seems that there may be a single evaluator?](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate)  ("Evaluator is a special task that is not part of the training cluster.")

Once I realized that tf.metrics.precision_at_k calculates precision at k within class predictions for a given row / data point and not , I have considered writing a custom metric function to call from within the Estimator train_and_evaluate method that keeps an internal dict of session ID to tuples of labels and predictions, and transforms these into Tensors to feed to tf.metrics.precision_at_k.

Caveats:

- I don't know if I can store this dict, as I don't think I can put it in the computational graph.  Can / should I try to store its state in the metric method itself?  Will that even be retained after the graph is created, and will it be correctly accessed on subsequent calls to the method?
- I don't know how or if I can group items with the same session ID onto the same executor -- even if a method like group_by_window or group_by_reducer on the Dataset works, how does this affect locality in a distributed context?
- I could reduce my eval set size to fit into memory but I don't know how to force this to run on only one executor.

I haven't had much luck finding any examples or more information online about anything like this, and the TF code and docs can be somewhat unhelpful, so I'd appreciate any advice!  Thanks!